# I want to move an item in sitecore with specific version and specific language to another instance. How can i achieve this?

Tags: sitecore

I have a multilingual site and I have an item which has many versions. I want to move that item to another instance of Sitecore which should only contain one language and one version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Clone the item in your current instance
2. Prepare the cloned item for moving to another instance: keep the required content and language versions only and delete others
3. Create a standard Sitecore content package and include your ready item to it
4. Install the content package consisting of the required item only in the right language version onto another instance